# In Oracle SQL will DELETE statement be commited by COMMIT in procedure called after it?

Tags: oracle, transactions, commit, dml

I have a procedure A where a DELETE is performed without COMMIT after it.
In this same procedure A another procedure B is called after the mentioned DELETE statement.
Procedure B contains just an INSERT with COMMIT.
Does this COMMIT (in procedure B) apply also to the DELETE executed in procedure A?

Comment: the DML within the procedure A succeeds even if only a DDL statement is issued within B.

Comment: I guess that happens because DDL statements are auto-committed, thus acting as if they include a COMMIT that apply to the whole transaction, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it also does for the procedure A if and only if the procedure B is not marked as an autonomous transaction.

Comment: For the benefit of the OP (and other readers), I would add the observation that the autonomous transaction thing works the other way, too. If a COMMIT statement appears in the same procedure (A) as the DELETE, and it appears after DELETE, but the COMMIT is within an autonomous transaction within A, the COMMIT will not commit the DELETE (even though it is **in the same procedure** and it comes after DELETE).